# Database query: join tags with exact matches or at least one

Tags: mysql

Given I have a query like:

```
SELECT count(mm.id) AS c
FROM merchant_mobile mm
INNER JOIN mobile m ON mm.mobile_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN merchant_mobile_customer mmc ON (mm.id = mmc.merchant_mobile_id)
INNER JOIN merchant_mobile_tag mmt ON mm.id = mmt.merchantmobile_id
INNER JOIN tag t ON t.id = mmt.tag_id
WHERE mm.merchant_id = ?
  AND mm.status LIKE ?
  AND (mm.last_promo_sms_date <= ?
       OR mm.last_promo_sms_date IS NULL)
  AND t.name = ?
  AND t.name = ?
ORDER BY mm.last_promo_sms_date ASC
```

I need to perform queries to select:

1. Matches for exact tag combination: eg: pretty AND blonde
2. Matches for any combination, but at least one of them: pretty OR blonde

Is it possible to make with just one query?
Do I need a subquery?
Is my schema ok?

[image: Database schema]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

1. For exact combination

   ```
   SELECT count(mm.id) AS c
   FROM merchant_mobile mm
   INNER JOIN mobile m ON mm.mobile_id = m.id
   LEFT JOIN merchant_mobile_customer mmc ON (mm.id = mmc.merchant_mobile_id)
   INNER JOIN merchant_mobile_tag mmt ON mm.id = mmt.merchantmobile_id
   INNER JOIN tag t ON t.id = mmt.tag_id
   WHERE mm.merchant_id = ?
     AND mm.status LIKE ?
     AND (mm.last_promo_sms_date <= ?
          OR mm.last_promo_sms_date IS NULL)
     AND mm.id IN
       (SELECT mm.id
        FROM merchant_mobile_customer mmc
        JOIN merchant_mobile mm ON mm.id = mmc.merchant_mobile_id
        JOIN merchant_mobile_tag mmt ON mm.id = mmt.merchantmobile_id
        RIGHT JOIN tag t ON mmt.tag_id = t.id
        WHERE t.name = ?
          OR t.name = ?
          OR t.name = ?
          AND mm.merchant_id = ?
        GROUP BY mm.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 )
   ORDER BY mm.last_promo_sms_date ASC ;
   ```
2. For at least one

   ```
   SELECT count(mm.id) AS c
   FROM merchant_mobile mm
   INNER JOIN mobile m ON mm.mobile_id = m.id
   LEFT JOIN merchant_mobile_customer mmc ON (mm.id = mmc.merchant_mobile_id)
   INNER JOIN merchant_mobile_tag mmt ON mm.id = mmt.merchantmobile_id
   INNER JOIN tag t ON t.id = mmt.tag_id
   WHERE mm.merchant_id = ?
     AND mm.status LIKE ?
     AND (mm.last_promo_sms_date <= ?
          OR mm.last_promo_sms_date IS NULL)
     AND mm.id IN
       ( SELECT mm.id
        FROM merchant_mobile_customer mmc
        JOIN merchant_mobile mm ON mm.id = mmc.merchant_mobile_id
        JOIN merchant_mobile_tag mmt ON mm.id = mmt.merchantmobile_id
        RIGHT JOIN tag t ON mmt.tag_id = t.id
        WHERE t.name = ?
          OR t.name = ?
          AND mm.merchant_id = ? )
   ORDER BY mm.last_promo_sms_date ASC ;
   ```

Comment: need help to format the sql in the answer